# Hide FormOne in a function, Show FormTwo, then Hide FormTwo and continue with FormOne where it's stopped

Tags: c#, show-hide

So, in my code I've already done Hide and Show Form, but when I go back to my FormOne, I don't know how to continue where it's stopped. For ex :

In FormOne:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            ObjTwo objTwo = new ObjTwo();
            objTwo.RefToFormOne = this;
            this.Hide();
            ObjTwo.Show();

            ***string variable = ObjTwo.variable;           
            anotherFuction();***

        }
```

In formTwo:

```
{
 public Form RefToFormOne { get; set; }  

 private void input_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
       
            string variable = input_textBox.Text;                                       
        }
   private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            RefToFormOne.Show();            
        }
}
```

So, what I want is: when I go back to Form One (after I've click okay button in FormTwo), I want to continue the function after where FormTwo is shown (bold text).
Can anyone help me? I'm trying to figure out this problem for a long time :(

Comment: Why aren't you just showing Form2 as modal? Showing/hiding forms like that is not a typical UI experience.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Show`, you can use `ShowDialog` which acts just like show except it pauses the calling method.

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1

***IF THE ABOVE DOES NOT WORK***

You can, in the first form, create a function to receive a call from the second form when the second form is hidden.

---

So in the first form:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ObjTwo objTwo = new ObjTwo();
    objTwo.RefToFormOne = this;
    this.Hide();
    ObjTwo.Show();
    //PUT EVERYTHING IN THE FUNCTION BELOW
}

public void ShowFormAndDoYourStuff()
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

---

And in the second form:

```
//Instead of this:
//public Form RefToFormOne { get; set; }  
//Do this below:
public Form1 RefToFormOne { get; set; }

private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    RefToFormOne.Show();
    RefToFormOne.ShowFormAndDoYourStuff();           
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with Andy, your code should look like this:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        var addPerson = new AddPersonDialog();
        addPerson.ShowDialog();

        string personName = addPerson.PersonName;           
        anotherFuction();

    }
```

And in the second form

```
class AddPersonDialog{

    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    private void input_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        PersonName = input_textBox.Text;                                       
    }

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();           
    }
}
```

This is a standard ui way of having a form that appears in front of a previous form, preventing the previous form from being used until the front form is dismissed. Like every save dialog you ever used.

ShowDialog conceptually pauses at the place it is called and only continues when the form that is ShowDialog'd is dismissed (like when you do a MessageBox.Show)

Be careful with your use of variable and class names. In your original code you used `ObjTwo objTwo = new ObjTwo; ObjTwo.Show()` i.e. you made an instance but then ignored the instance and tried to call Show on the class instead. It might even work, with forms, in some contexts of .NET - VB at least has this awful "trick" where it auto-makes an instance of every form on the application and calls them the name of the class - but in c# a variable cannot have the same name as a type and C# doesn't take the same auto-create steps so ObjTwo.Show() is not a thing (it'll give a "an object reference is required" error)

---

I also took the liberty of using more descriptive variable names in this example (though I left anotherFuction alone because it was amusing). When you're coding, please use more apt names than "class1", "obj2", "variable", "textboxX" - not only do we have to understand your code when you ask for help but YOU have to understand it in 6 months time when you have to fix a problem with it. Trying to read code that is a constant translation exercise of "is it textbox23 or textbox27 that stores the Person Name? I'll open the form and have a look" is incredibly wearisome, and totally unnecessary when it takes two seconds to click in the (name) line of the textbox properties grid after you drop it on a form, and write `personNameTextbox`

"The first step to wisdom is by calling things their proper names" - Chinese proverb

Comment: Thank you so much. I've just started to learn this. And thank you for your exponentiation. Yes, I know about the naming that it's not correct way to use name like that . In my project I used other names for the functions, objects and etc. However, thank you again.